# How to plot multiple 1 dimensional scatter plot in R based on occurences of a specific value at a specific point of x-axis

Tags: r, plot

I have these datas that determines how absence rate affect student's grade in 3 different years, im trying to plot a one dimensional scatter plot with the three different years in the y-axis G1, G2 and G3 while absences being the x-axis. The one dimensional scatter plot should plot occurences of grade = 0 in specific absences value, something like the picture provided below.

desired output:
[image]

my data:

```
structure(list(absences = c("6", "4", "10", "2", "4", "10", "0", 
"6", "o", "0", "0", "4", "2", "2", "0", "4", "6", "4", "16", 
"4"), G1 = c(5, 5, 7, 15, 6, 15, 12, 6, 16, 14, 10, 10, 14, 10, 
14, 14, 13, 8, 6, 8), G2 = c(6, 5, 8, 14, 10, 15, 12, 5, 18, 
15, 8, 12, 14, 10, 16, 14, 14, 10, 5, 10), G3 = c(6, 6, 10, 15, 
10, 15, 11, 6, 19, 15, 9, 12, 14, 11, 16, 14, 14, 10, 5, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(absences = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), G1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), G2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), G3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = "\t"), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x55e465b58110>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2022)
tibble(
  absences = sample(c(0:16), 20, replace = TRUE), 
  G1 = sample(c(0:16), 20, replace = TRUE), 
  G2 = sample(c(0:16), 20, replace = TRUE), 
  G3 = sample(c(0:16), 20, replace = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -absences,
    names_to = "key",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  filter(key != 0) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(absences, key)) +
  #geom_jitter(color = "red", height = 0.1)
  geom_point(color = "red")
```

I didn't know if your grades and absences are distinct. if not, you can use the `geom_jitter()` I quoted out.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how you could start to achieve your task:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -absences
  ) %>% 
  mutate(absences = as.numeric(replace(absences, absences == "o", "0"))) %>% 
  group_by(absences, name, value) %>% 
  summarise(absences = sum(absences, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=factor(absences)))+
  geom_point(aes(size = value), color="red")+
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(title = "Your title", y ="Absences", x = "Year") + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(color= guide_legend(), size=guide_legend())+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]